# Flask Restful - Status 400 when using parser_args() to add arguments to requests in python

Tags: python, flask-restful

I am trying to use flask_restful to create an API using Python. I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Example(Resource):

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('some_arg')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return {"Param Entered": args['some_arg']}

api.add_resource(Example, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When running the GET request in Postman:

```
GET <my_url>/?some_arg=<some_text>
```

I get the error: **"message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."**

Could someone please explain why this error shows and how I can add arguments properly using parse_args() for flask restful? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but I also got the issue and managed to solve it by chaning `parser.add_argument('some_arg')` to `parser.add_argument('some_arg', location='args')`.

Without the location parameter, it was working fine on my Windows machine, but not on my Linux one (EC2 instance).

Comment: Thank you this worked for me too on MacOs Monterey 12.5

Comment: before it was working fine without `location='args'` on Linux, but now maybe they changed something in the flask library